# do an exception on first td with Filter Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

He want to do an input box with a Filter Table options.
My input box is:

```
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
```

and this code to generate a table:

```
   $data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                            <tr>
                                                    <th>No.</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                                    <th>Email Address</th>
                                                    <th>Update</th>
                                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                            </tr>';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
```

and my js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

is it necessary to use a tbody or anything else to do a Filter Table?
or not’s possible to do an exception for the first  ?

very thanks!

Comment: Having a thead and tbody would be a pretty clear distinction between the header and the data.  Is it necessary?  No.  It could be done other ways.  Is using a tbody super easy for this case.  Yes, very.

Comment: It's not necessary to use thead/tbody, but it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

yes, is possible to do an exception for the first. Try something like:

```
$('table tr:gt(1)').filter...
```

(Your header has 1 row, so it will work)

Answer (score 0):

I do it!

Finally with this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var $value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr:gt(0)").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```